# how can move child tag to child

Tags: perl

I new to [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig).

I need move child tag to child tag.

How can I do this?

When I match `notes` tag that parent tag with child move to before section.

My XML looks like this:

```xml
<book>
  <sec>
    <p>The indicated something</p>
    <p>The something</p>
  </sec>
  <sec>
    <notes>note</notes>
    <p>text</p>
  </sec>

  <sec>
    <p>The indicated</p>
    <p>The something</p>
  </sec>
  <sec>
    <notes>note</notes>
    <p>text1</p>
  </sec>

</book>
```

I tried:

```perl
use XML::Twig;

open(my $output, ">output.xml") || die "can't open the output.xml$!\n";

my $story_file = XML::Twig->new(
    keep_encoding => 1,
    twig_handlers => { 'book' => \&book, },
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
);
$story_file->parse("sample.xml");
$story_file->print($output);
$story_file->purge;

sub book {
    my ($stroy_file, $book) = @_;
    my @sub_elmt = $book->children;
    Get_children(\@sub_elmt) if ($#sub_elmt >= 0);
}

sub Get_children {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    foreach my $tagg (@$ref) {
        my @children = $tagg->children;
        my $tagName  = $tagg->name;
        if ($tagName =~ /^sec$/) {
            my $f = $tagg->first_child;
            if ($f->name =~ /^notes$/) {
                $tagg->move('last_child', $tagg);
            }
        }
        Get_children(\@children) if ($#children >= 0);
    }
}
```

It can't work, How can I do this?

I need the output like this:

```xml
<book>
  <sec>
    <p>The indicated something</p>
    <p>The something</p>
    <sec>
      <notes>note</notes>
      <p>text</p>
    </sec>
  </sec>
  <sec>
    <p>The indicated</p>
    <p>The something</p>
    <sec>
      <notes>note</notes>
      <p>text1</p>
    </sec>
  </sec>
</book>
```

How I do this?

Comment: Please indent your program properly to show the structure. It is unreadable as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XML::Twig` can be very useful for processing very large XML documents piece by piece using `twig_handlers`, but you don't *have* to use it like that. It will build a complete XML document tree and let you manipulate that tree and print it out just like most other XML modules.

This program reads the whole document from `sample.xml`, then searches for all `notes` elements that are inside a `sec` element. The containing `sec` element is found using `parent`, and the previous `sec` element (into which this is to be inserted) is found using `prev_sibling`. Then `move` is used to reposition the `sec` element as the last child of the preceding `sec`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile('sample.xml');

for my $notes ( $twig->findnodes('//sec/notes') ) {
  my $sec = $notes->parent;
  my $prev_sec = $sec->prev_sibling('sec');
  $sec->move(last_child => $prev_sec);
}

$twig->print_to_file('output.xml', pretty_print => 'indented');
```

**output**

```xml
<book>
  <sec>
    <p>The indicated something</p>
    <p>The something</p>
    <sec>
      <notes>note</notes>
      <p>text</p>
    </sec>
  </sec>
  <sec>
    <p>The indicated</p>
    <p>The something</p>
    <sec>
      <notes>note</notes>
      <p>text1</p>
    </sec>
  </sec>
</book>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos both in your XML and in your Perl script.  NB. I've amended & tidied up your XML examples (see *notes* tag).

Your main issue is that `$tagg->move` is moving to `$tagg` (ie. itself!) so that won't work :(

Below is my simplified version which does what you require (ie. when it sees a `book/sec` tag with first child `notes` then it moves this `sec` to end of previous `sec`) and demonstrates how `->move` works.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig; 

my $book_sec = do {
    my $last_sec;
    sub {
        my ($twig, $sec) = @_;

        # if <sec> has first child <notes> then this needs
        # to be moved to end of previous <sec>

        $sec->move( 'last_child', $last_sec ) 
            if $sec->first_child('notes') && $last_sec;

        $last_sec = $sec;   # cache that last <sec>
    };
};

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => { 'book/sec' => $book_sec },
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
)->parsefile( 'sample.xml' )->print_to_file( 'output.xml' );
```